# Map in Mongodb with aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my Data in DB

```
{
name: abc
    pro: 1
    },
    {
    name:cde,
    pro: 2
    },
    {
name:fgh,
    pro:3
    },
    {
name:ijk,
    pro:4
    },
```

**here is my query to aggregate the result I've successfully get the count of name and pro**:

```
db.aggregate([
        {
          $facet: {
           
            "name": [
              { $group: { _id: '$name', N: { $sum: 1 } } }
            ],
},{ $project: {  "pro": {
              $map: {
                input: '$pro',
                in:{ $arrayToObject: [[{ k: '$$this._id', v: '$$this.N'}]] }
              }
            },
}}])
```

**For `pro` which is `1` in DB but against 1, I want to map `a` etc, in response.**

**Expecting Output**:

```
{
        name: abc
        pro: a //value in DB is 1.
        },
        {
        name:cde,
        pro: b //value in DB is 2.
        },
        {
        name:fgh,
        pro:c //value in DB is 3
        },
        {
        name:ijk,
        pro:d //value in DB is 4
        },
}
```

Comment: what if pro is greater than 26, what should be the mapped value then?

Comment: No it's not that kind of thing, Pro has some values 1,2,3,4. All I want to map `a` to 1 , and `b` to 2, so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to map `pro` integer values to corresponding characters. Then this should work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      pro: {
        $slice: [
          [
            "",
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d"
          ],
          "$pro",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$pro"
  }
])
```

Here is the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yp5QoY_-RFn).

Comment: Project pipeline looks like I've mentioned above.

Comment: What is the use of facet in your pipeline? Please create a minimal reproducible example of what is expected from your pipeline on Mongodb Playground

Comment: [here it is](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zS_hCViG9lD)

Comment: it is giving error

Comment: [updated](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cgNYvDr8eke)

Comment: Still not working, please create the example with your sample data, in running condition. Also please reframe your question if possible it is not clear what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map pro function, it will works

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  name: 1,
  pro: {
    $slice: [
      [
        "",
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
      ],
      "$pro",
      1
    ]
  }
}
},
{
 "$unwind": "$pro"
}
])
```

Comment: I've tried this, but unfortunately No luck.